# why do i keep getting a "Method not allowed" on my html template whenever i try using http.MethodDelete?

Tags: go

I am using http.MethodDelete to try and delete quotes from my html template. Everytime i press the delete button i get the error message.

I tried using this inside my html template, "Delete " but it still gives me the error.

Comment: this is my github link for the project, https://github.com/abelwhite/quotes.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It sounds like a CORS error. Your target server must allow DELETE method...  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,CREATE,DELETE")

Comment: @radgeek Rather than link to a GitHub gist, make your question self-contained by including a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```golang
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodDelete, "/quote/delete", app.quoteDelete)
```

```html
<a class="delete-button" href="/quote/delete?quote_id={{ .QuoteID}}">Delete</a>
```

By default, a browser follows a link by sending a `GET` request. It does not send a `DELETE` request as you expected.

You can send a `DELETE` request using JavaScript code.

It seems that you haven't written any JavaScript code in your project, so a quick fix is to modify the server code to handle the `POST` request and use a form to send a `POST` request to the delete resource endpoint:

```golang
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodPost, "/quote/delete", app.quoteDelete)
```

```html
<form action="/quote/delete?quote_id={{ .QuoteID }}" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

---

Please note that a form can not be used to send a `DELETE` request. The allowed methods of a from element are listed on [the doc for the Form element from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

> `method`
>
> The HTTP method to submit the form with. The only allowed methods/values are (case insensitive):
>
> - `post`: The POST method; form data sent as the request body.
> - `get` (default): The GET; form data appended to the action URL with a ? separator. Use this method when the form has no side effects.
> - `dialog`: When the form is inside a `<dialog>`, closes the dialog and causes a submit event to be fired on submission, without submitting data or clearing the form.

And for the definition of HTTP request methods, see [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).